# Not able to detect the line number in logcat Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat

Android Studio 2.2.3

Android Studio is not able to detect the line number in logcat. Is there any way to solve this? It show  **Unknown Source** in place of line no.

**LOGCAT is added just the shake of pointing what is the issue. Not to point why NULL POINT EXCEPTION occuring...**

Please ignore the error( I know why it is occurring ). I have added the logout to show what is problem.

Android studio is showing Unknown Source instead of error line number.

Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: user.com.hlthee, PID: 1107
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at user.com.hlthee.Reminders$13.onClick(**Unknown Source**)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you can post a picture

Comment: hey @Charuka I have added the logcat.

Comment: check my answer

Comment: please note when you edit a question post it under EDIT part and your question is about a specific occurrence but you ask it like you have it every time when you have an error and i have given the reason for that specific  scenario

Comment: I am editing the question because I think I have written in the wrong way. I want to ask something else and I am pointing to the different question.

Comment: still do you have your issue?

Comment: I didn't get the answer so need to format the android studio. Now no problem. Still wondering why this problem occurred? @Charuka

Comment: Now again the same issue starts@Charuka

Comment: whatabout your naming conventions ? do you use dependancies for button effects

Comment: i do not get you @Charuka naming conventions?

Comment: when you name a package/class name there is a stranded,and also rules  not even class names simply if you use caps to name an image in drawble it's a problem case. same thing was with your previous class name

Comment: I have double check there is no resource with the first character capital and also the class name/package naming also follow the google guidelines. The previous class means i think you are talking about Reminders$13  class name. But in actual it is Reminders.java that I don't know why android studio has shown like that.

Answer (score 4):

If it is your class(Not a library) you are missing a view in your XML connected to the class. It says as **NullPointerException - onClick(**Unknown Source**)** meaning in your class you probably used `onclick` funtion for that view but the view is not in the XML. Find where you added `onClick`s in your class and see which one is not present in your connected XML

**Edit :**

This *Unknown Source* can occur if you do not have a proper naming conventions for your package name and package tag in your manifest like below

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="string"
          android:sharedUserId="string"
          android:sharedUserLabel="string resource" 
          android:versionCode="integer"
          android:versionName="string"
          android:installLocation=["auto" | "internalOnly" | "preferExternal"] >
    . . .
</manifest>
```

So you can double check your activity tag as well and follow naming conventions.
You might have a name something like this ..`Reminders$13`

[image]

> A full Java-language-style package name for the Android application.
>   The name should be unique. The name may contain uppercase or lowercase
>   letters ('A' through 'Z'), numbers, and underscores ('_'). However,
>   individual package name parts may only start with letters. To avoid
>   conflicts with other developers, you should use Internet domain
>   ownership as the basis for your package names (in reverse). For
>   example, applications published by Google start with com.google. You
>   should also never use the com.example namespace when publishing your
>   applications.

From [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html)

Comment: hey think you have understand my question wrongly... My question is.. I know where is the error but why don't it pointing to the line number ( or showing )  where is error...

Comment: because it cannot link them,compiler ignored it maybe you have same id with another xml so compiler cannot do the job and when run-time it try to find and return the view there is none in that xml it confuses and displayed as **Unknown Source)** but as a hint it says where that can occur  "user.com.hlthee.Reminders$13.onClick"

Comment: @Ankur Khandelwal you have not mentioned that "I know where is the error" either in your question

Comment: sorry. for the misunderstanding. Now I have written in the question @Charuka

Comment: I am not asking why null point exception occurred, I am saying irrespective to the error, the android studio is not telling me in which line the error is occurring.

Answer (score 2):

the possibilities that you are seeing **Unknown Source** are because either your device connection has been **lost** or the application's **main thread is killed**,
It will be more clear if you put screen shot here

Comment: its more clear if you add your answer as a comment :P

Comment: I have added the logcat.. @kalpit

Comment: I can see in your logcat there is line ` at user.com.hlthee.Reminders$13.onClick(**Unknown Source**)`
where $13 is line number i suppose. 
check what are you pasing in onClick it should be view class or its subclass

Comment: $13 is not the line no.